# Magento Quick Search - Products Not showing

Tags: php, mysql, magento

For some reason when using quick search for some products they don't show in the results. The products do exist and are on stock, enabled etc and can be found on the store from navigating through the catolg, and yes the attribute is set to be searchable be 'catlog, search'

I've reindexed data, and cleaered the cache. I've even tried disabling the cache.

But still can't get it to work, anyone got any more ideas? I've searched on the forums and other people expreicning same problem, but can't see any decent solutions - or that works for me.

Please help :-)

Cheers

Shane

Comment: I have similar problems. File a bug report with Magento or implement your own search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's to do with MySQL Full text search being set to 4 chars.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Would you tell what you did to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

In our case we had category-based block caching for the layered navigation, breaking the search result page as no category id was given.

Try to track it down and remove the layered navigation from catalogsearch_result_index by putting comments around it:

```
    <!--<reference name="left">
        <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not got any weird synonyms set have you? Happened on one of my projects when we helpfully imported a load of auto corrected historic search data and had a few oddities imported along with them.

Comment: No not what I know of... still not sure whats going on, I've got a new product spreadsheet which I need to upload from the client so I'm hoping that if I re-upload it will sort itself out, fingers crossed! :-)